# Different signatures on passport and on ID card

Tags: passports, paperwork, pakistani-citizens

I have a Pakistani passport. I want to know whether signature on passport should be same as on Identity card or it can be different?

Answer (score 11):

**Nobody bothers (you) about that**. When you go abroad and present your passport, they don't ask you to also present your national identity card to cross match the signatures.

Many countries don't even have a separate national ID card.

Unless someday they start doubting your identity. On such a day this can become a headache. At that point, everything must line up (not necessarily *match* up still). As long as its a legitimate case you will be good.

Keep your ID card well protected and away from the passport when you are going abroad, You don't want to lose both things together someday. You do not have to present your national ID card to immigration officers if you are presenting a valid passport, unless specifically requested. There is no compulsion to even carry it, except for a rainy day.

Comment: While this may or may not be correct, is this really such good advice? This seems like exactly the kind of thing that will make officials suspicious if they do find it out, a signature is by its very definition a mark that you make similarly enough every time you make it that it's possible to use it to identify you as being who you claim to be.

Comment: I know a number of people who are unable to make two identical signatures. This seems pretty common to me. Issues arise when bank gets a check from you with a signature different than the specimen you provided them.

Comment: @Cronax, while its good that they both match up but in most cases they do not ask for a national identity card and do not try to match up your signatures. If you have the wrong signatures on your passport they don't have a way to verify that against your national ID card. You don't even have to carry your national ID card when you are carrying a valid passport.

Comment: There are several countries where a national ID card is a light version of a passport, which leads to the situation that people have either none or one of the two (e.g. the Netherlands).

Comment: @Cronax And it probably depends on the two signatures. If one is perfect penmanship and the other is chicken scratch, I might be suspicious. If they are two different sloppy signatures, I wouldn't think too much on it.

Comment: @DavidK I'm not suggesting they always need to be identical, I am only suggesting that they should be reasonably similar to the casual observer.

Comment: I live in a country with a byzantine banking system that still heavily relies on signatures. I'm unable to have a stable signature and I always, always have to try a few times before the teller accepts it. Why, oh why, a signature is considered valid authentication in the third millennium?